# How to format the code on click of a button in @monaco-editor/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor

how to format the code inside the monaco editor when user clicks the `show code` button? I have tried `formatOnPaste: true` but it seems not working when you update the code programmatically (using useState)

here is the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/monaco-editor-react-test-code-dbof2u?file=/src/App.tsx) (make sure to click `show code` button)

```
import Editor from "@monaco-editor/react";
import { useState } from "react";


export default function App() {
  const [code, setCode] = useState("");

  const handleShowCodeClick = () => {
    const newCode = "const consoleText = (text) => {console.log(text)}";
    setCode(newCode);
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Editor
        value={code}
        height="500px"
        theme="vs-dark"
        options={{
          formatOnPase: true
        }}
        language="javascript"
        onChange={(newCode) => setCode(newCode as string)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleShowCodeClick}>Show code</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the actual result:

```
const consoleText = (text) => {console.log(text)}
```

the expected result:

```
const consoleText = (text) => {
  console.log(text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing this in case anyone is using `monaco-editor/react` & wants to format the editor contents using a button.

I had some luck using a method such as this:

```
  const handleEditorDidMount = (editor, monaco) => {
    // "monacoRef" was instantiated using React.useRef()
    monacoRef.current = editor;

    // this setTimeout is just a proof of concept (or test)
    setTimeout(() => {
      monacoRef.current.hb.get('editor.action.formatDocument').b();
    }, 1000);
  };
```

```
  <Editor
    // props
    onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
  />
```

I used this method to pass the `ref` to a different component which has a button; then called the function the same way.

Comment: I made changes to your sandbox example; you can find my updated one here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/l42nv8

not sure why the function is nested differently in this example than the answer I gave above... I'm still learning monaco. Also, this doesn't appear to format the code exactly how you wanted, but it does at least appear to be formatting the code.